# How to illustrate an "UX approved" stamp?

Tags: ux-field, sharing, onboarding, team, skills

I'm looking for a ways to convey the idea of `good` *vs.* `bad`* UX design and features. In order to offer a UX stamp(s) to my girlfriend as she is a *Human Factor Engineer*.

The idea is neither to stigmatize people nor errors but to **raise awareness** of the help she can provide as well as *skills* and **process needed to achieve good products**.

Do you have feedbacks ?

Comment: When you say 'stamp' are you talking about a literal rubber stamp? I'm not clear on the context.

Comment: could be a either physical or virtual stamp.

Comment: This sounds like a graphic design question. Typical concepts would be thumbs up/down. Checkmark/x. etc.

Comment: It is a graphic design question in my opinion too. The primary need is to invent a symbol that communicates the message.

Comment: The "how" of the the stamp is a design question. How will the ideas be communicated. But the "what" of the stamp is arguably a UX question, and a very difficult one to boot. What are the core ideas that best represent the ethos and value of UX, on the limited canvas of stamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, a simple "seal of approval" is actually rather detrimental to the idea of user centered design, and especially to the practitioner's merit.

Any approval (or disapproval) should be met with rationale; that is how one raises awareness and illustrates skills needed to achieve good products. You can't put that in a stamp. If a Human Factors (UX, Usability, Ergonomics, etc...) practitioner want's to put their "seal of approval" on something, it should be in the first paragraph (or be the first bullet) of a report explaining why.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2vI8Q.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I was thinking to this as an informal channel, but it might be a silly idea

Answer (score 2):

When trying to introduce others to usability, IA, UX, accessibility, Plain English, I find it helps to give examples of good practice contrasted with bad practice, and an explanation of why the good example is good and the bad example is bad.

I usually flag the good example with a tick on a green background and the bad example with a x on a red background.

That also neatly illustrates how to offer more information than just a red or green background to indicate status (because of colour-blindness).

Whatever you use to indicate approval, the cultural context would need to be taken into account. A thumbs-up may mean different things in different cultures, for example.

Comment: The usability.gov website has quite a nice approval rating system
http://guidelines.usability.gov/guidelines/106

Answer (score -1):

I like bar graphs myself. Remember you want to convey information not just data. Perhaps an overall score and then a bar graph for things like cognitive load, information architecture and flow.